# Error: The resource in the URL content has exceeded the maximum size. - Is it possible to reproduce IMPORTXML by script to avoid problems like this?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("-",TRIM(IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr[3]/th[2]/b | //tr[3]/th[3]/b | //tr[3]/th[7]/b | //tr[3]/th[8]/b | //tr[3]/th[9]/b | //tr[3]/th[16]/b"))))="Host-Guest-1-X-2-2.5",
{IMPORTXML(IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href"),"//tr/td[2]/a"),
IMPORTXML(IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href"),"//tr/td[3]/a"),
ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(TEXT(1/QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href"),"//tr/td[7]"),"HX",""),"Where Col1 is not null"),"0.00"))),
ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(TEXT(1/QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href"),"//tr/td[8]"),"H2",""),"Where Col1 is not null"),"0.00"))),
ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(TEXT(1/QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href"),"//tr/td[9]"),"HX",""),"Where Col1 is not null"),"0.00"))),
ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(TEXT(1/QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href"),"//tr/td[16]"),"hc2",""),"Where Col1 is not null"),"0.00")))},
"Off")
```

Even earlier today it was working perfectly, showing all the data. But from now on this same error always appears, even if I try to import something very simple, like:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href")
```

I would like to know if it is possible to reproduce this (the complete import that I put at the beginning of the question) import through Google App Script (GAS) and if someone could show me how it would look, that way there would be no more limit problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to convert the formula in your question to Google Apps Script.
- The base URL is `http://old.statarea.com/`.
- You want to retrieve the values by changing the data URL with `IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href")` and `IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[5]/@href")`.
- As the values, you want to retrieve `td[7]`, `td[8]`, `td[9]` and `td[16]`.
- For example, you want to calculate the retrieved value of `50%` as `1 / 0.5`, and want to use it as the value for putting to Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Flow:

In this case, I retrieve the values you want by 3 steps.

1. Retrieve a part of values from the HTML using Parser which is a Google Apps Script library.
2. Parse the retrieved HTML with XmlService by removing the unnecessary values.
3. Retrieve the result values using XmlService.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install "Parser"

Please install a Google Apps Script library of ["Parser"](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html).

#### 2. Sample script 1:

This is a sample script. In this script, you can use this as the custom function. So please put a formula of `=sample(5)` to a cell.

```
function sample(placeOfUrl) {
  // Retrieve URL.
  var baseUrl = "http://old.statarea.com/";
  var res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl);
  if (res1.getResponseCode() != 200) throw new Erro("URL cannot be used.");
  const from = '<td style="padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">';
  const to = '&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
  const htmlData1 = (from + Parser.data(res1.getContentText()).from(from).to(to).build() + to).replace(/\&nbsp;/g, "");
  const xmlRoot = XmlService.parse(htmlData1).getRootElement();
  const c = xmlRoot.getChildren()[placeOfUrl - 1];
  if (!c) return;
  const url = c.getAttribute("href").getValue();

  // Parse HTML data.
  const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  if (res2.getResponseCode() != 200) throw new Erro("URL for retrieving data cannot be used.");
  const htmlData2 = res2.getContentText();
  const parsedData1 = Parser.data(htmlData2).from('<table class="style_1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="918" border="0">').to('</table>').build();
  const parsedData2 = Parser.data(parsedData1).from("<tr>").to("</tr>").iterate();
  const data = parsedData2
    .filter(function(e) {return /^<td width="35" align="center">/.test(e)})
    .map(function(e) {return "<content>" + e.match(/<td.+?\/td>/g).map(function(f) {return f.replace(/\&nbsp\;|<div.+?>|<\/div>|<img.+?>|<input.+?>|\&team_guest|<\/h.+?>|\&/g, "")}).join("") + "</content>"})
    .join("");
  const xmlRootContent = XmlService.parse("<root>" + data + "</root>").getRootElement();

  // Retrieve result values.
  const content = xmlRootContent.getChildren();
  const values = content.reduce((ar1, e) => {
    const temp = e.getChildren().reduce((ar2, f, j) => {
      if (f) {
        if (f.getChild("a")) {
          const t = f.getChild("a").getValue()
          if (t) ar2.push(t);
        } else {
          if (f.getAttribute("style")) {
            const v = f.getValue();
            if (v && [6, 7, 8, 15].includes(j)) {
              ar2.push(Math.round((1 / (parseInt(v, 10) / 100)) * 100) / 100);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return ar2;
    }, []);
    ar1.push(temp);
    return ar1;
  }, []);

  return values;
}
```

- When `=sample(4)` is set, the data URL is the same with `IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href")`.
- When `=sample(5)` is set, the data URL is the same with `IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[5]/@href")`.

Result:

[image]

#### 3. Sample script 2:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. In this case, the container-bound script is used. When you run the script at the script editor, the values are put to the Spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var placeOfUrl = "5";  // Here, you can change the URL for retrieving values.

  // Retrieve URL.
  var baseUrl = "http://old.statarea.com/";
  var res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl);
  if (res1.getResponseCode() != 200) throw new Erro("URL cannot be used.");
  const from = '<td style="padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">';
  const to = '&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
  const htmlData1 = (from + Parser.data(res1.getContentText()).from(from).to(to).build() + to).replace(/\&nbsp;/g, "");
  const xmlRoot = XmlService.parse(htmlData1).getRootElement();
  const c = xmlRoot.getChildren()[placeOfUrl - 1];
  if (!c) return;
  const url = c.getAttribute("href").getValue();

  // Parse HTML data.
  const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  if (res2.getResponseCode() != 200) throw new Erro("URL for retrieving data cannot be used.");
  const htmlData2 = res2.getContentText();
  const parsedData1 = Parser.data(htmlData2).from('<table class="style_1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="918" border="0">').to('</table>').build();
  const parsedData2 = Parser.data(parsedData1).from("<tr>").to("</tr>").iterate();
  const data = parsedData2
    .filter(function(e) {return /^<td width="35" align="center">/.test(e)})
    .map(function(e) {return "<content>" + e.match(/<td.+?\/td>/g).map(function(f) {return f.replace(/\&nbsp\;|<div.+?>|<\/div>|<img.+?>|<input.+?>|\&team_guest|<\/h.+?>|\&/g, "")}).join("") + "</content>"})
    .join("");
  const xmlRootContent = XmlService.parse("<root>" + data + "</root>").getRootElement();

  // Retrieve result values.
  const content = xmlRootContent.getChildren();
  const values = content.reduce((ar1, e) => {
    const temp = e.getChildren().reduce((ar2, f, j) => {
      if (f) {
        if (f.getChild("a")) {
          const t = f.getChild("a").getValue()
          if (t) ar2.push(t);
        } else {
          if (f.getAttribute("style")) {
            const v = f.getValue();
            if (v && [6, 7, 8, 15].includes(j)) {
              ar2.push(Math.round((1 / (parseInt(v, 10) / 100)) * 100) / 100);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return ar2;
    }, []);
    ar1.push(temp);
    return ar1;
  }, []);

  // Put values to Spreadsheet.
  var sheetname = "Sheet5";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When `var placeOfUrl = "4"` is set, the data URL is the same with `IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href")`.
- When `var placeOfUrl = "5"` is set, the data URL is the same with `IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[5]/@href")`.

### Note:

- I confirmed that in the GAS project in your shared Spreadsheet used V8. So above script also used V8. Please be careful this.
- When the size of HTML data from "http://old.statarea.com/" is near 1 MB, your formula can be used. But when the size of HTML data from "http://old.statarea.com/" is near 2 MB, the error occurs. This has already been mentioned in your question.

  - In this case, it seems that the URL is changed. When the size of HTML data from "http://old.statarea.com/" is near 1 MB, `var placeOfUrl = "4"` is the same URL from `IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href")`. But when the size of HTML data from "http://old.statarea.com/" is near 2 MB, `var placeOfUrl = "5"` is the same URL from `IMPORTXML("http://old.statarea.com/","//tr/td/a[4]/@href")`. But about this situation, I'm not sure whether this always occurs. I apologize for this.
- When the specification of page of URL is changed, the script cannot be used. So please be careful this.

### References:

- [Parser](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html)
- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike... Thank you so much for giving me this great help! Right now I can't do the tests, but as soon as possible I'll try it out. Whatever I thank you will be little to compare with your help, you have no idea how much it will help me!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. In the current stage, I could confirm that the script worked. But for example, if the limitation occurs in the future by the situation of the site specification, an error might occur. At that time, I apologize for this.